# Get angular constants in Karma

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

Given the app startup:

```
angular.module("starter", [ "ionic" ])
    .constant("DEBUG", true)
    .run(function() {
        /* ... */
    });
```

how would I test the value of `DEBUG`?

When trying with:

```
describe("app", function() {

    beforeEach(function() {
        module("starter");
    });

    describe("constants", function() {
        describe("DEBUG", inject(function(DEBUG) {
            it("should be a boolean", function() {
                expect(typeof DEBUG).toBe("boolean");
            });
        }));
    });
});
```

I just get

```
TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'currentSpec.$modules')
    at workFn (/%%%/www/lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2230)
    at /%%%/www/js/app_test.js:14
    at /%%%/www/js/app_test.js:15
    at /%%%/www/js/app_test.js:16
```

Comment: Show lines 14, 15, 16 of your "app_test.js"...

Comment: `app_test.js` is the second code block. Lines 14-16 are the last three lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure it is being instantiated in the right place.
In this case, the `beforeEach` was not being run to load the module, because `DEBUG` was being `inject()`ed in the `describe` block, not the `it` block. The following works properly:

```
describe("app", function() {

    var DEBUG;

    beforeEach(function() {
        module("starter");
    });

    describe("constants", function() {
        describe("DEBUG", function() {
            it("should be a boolean", inject(function(DEBUG) {
                expect(typeof DEBUG).toBe("boolean");
            }));
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple way to inject your existing constants into your karma tests.

```
// Assuming your constant already exists
angular.module('app').constant('STACK', 'overflow')...

// Your Karma Test Suite
describe('app', function() {
    var STACK;

    beforeEach(module('APP'));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
        STACK = $injector.get('STACK');
    }));

    // Tests...
});
```